# Magazine/Journal Class Structure and/or Design pattern

Tags: c#, xml, class, design-patterns

I have an xml document that holds all of our alumni magazines.

```
<Magazine>
  <Volumes>
    <Volume>
      <Issues>
        <Issue>
          <Sections>
            <Section>
              <Articles>
                <Article>
                  <Images>
                    <Image>
                    </Image>
                    ...
                  </Images>
                </Article>
                ...
              </Articles>
            </Section>
            ...
          </Sections>
        </Issue>
        ...
      </Issues>
    </Volume>
    ...
  </Volumes>
</Magazine>
```

I created a class for: Volume, Issue, Section, Article, and Image.

My question is: 
Should I create a hierarchy of super- and sub-classes?
i.e. -- Image inherits Article inherits Section inherits Issue inherits Volume
**Or**
Do I leave them separate and use Generic Collections as properties of the parent class?
i.e. -- Volume.Issues, Issue.Sections, Section.Articles, Article.Images
**Or**
Something else that I am completely unaware of?

What are the pros/cons/deficiencies of these choices?

EDIT:
If I'm using an Issue object, I also need to know the Volume number and Volume Year, as well as the Article Titles in each Section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance sounds completely wrong for your case. It should only be used when there is a natural hierarchical relationship present between your domain classes. A classical example would be to have

```
-Employee 
--Contractor
--Permanent
```

They will still all need names, addresses and similar methods like: hire(), fire(), pay().

In your case there is no relationship to inherit, and it's a classical example of why you should **favour composition over inheritance**.

A image is NOT an article, but an article HAS an image. This could be applied to your entire structure.

It's all about the 'has a' instead of 'is a'.

Comment: Thanks! I knew design patterns/principles could help in some way.

Now... off to find some tutorials on composing.

Comment: You are welcome. I'd say this boils down to the principles of OOD more than design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance if all classes has common properties/methods if not the inheritance will be meaningless.

You can use [`Linq To XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) to get all data you need from your xml document without mapping it to classes, or use [`Linq to Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397937.aspx) after mapping

Comment: Interesting. I need to study LINQ, apparently. Thanks for the linqs links.

Answer (score 0):

Exact answer is only when you will know how do you planning to use this data in your application, how data will be stored, how to be displayed etc.

Usually, article is a useful start-point class (similar to blog post etc.). You do not need Article inside Magazine (rather MagazineIssue)

```
    //search all articles in some Magazine issue
    public IList<Article> GetArticles(long ISBN, string issueNumber)
    {
        //implementation
    }
```

In some cases you also do not need Section class.

```
public class Article
{
    //can be immutable
    public MagazineIssueView Issue { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public IList<Section> Sections { get; set; }

    public IList<Image> GetAllArticleImages()
    {
        return Sections
            .SelectMany<Section, ContentBlock>(s => s.SectionContent)
            .Where(c => c is Image)
            .Cast<Image>()
            .ToList();
    }
}

public class MagazineIssueView
{
    public long ISBN { get; set; }

    //if you have internal Magazines list, it can be also internal MagazineId
    public string MagazineName { get; set; }

    public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }

    public string IssueNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Section
{
    public string SectionTitle { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public IList<ContentBlock> SectionContent { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ContentBlock
{
}

public class Image: ContentBlock
{
}

public class Paragraph: ContentBlock
{
}
```

Comment: I am listing each issue in a .net Repeater control with each issue's information (including it's volume number)

When **an** issue is requested (GET)... it will display a menu that links to its Sections (e.g. ThisCampus, OtherCampus, CollegeWide, CoverStory, AlumniNews, etc.) and each Section's Articles.

When an Article is requested, it will show the article and all images that belong to that article.

Are you suggesting that I omit Volume class and make Issue my access class?
This makes perfect sense... but how do I use the Volume information in an OO manner? Am I over-complicating matters?

Comment: Would it be better to make Volume an interface?

Comment: Seems like Volume class is MagazineIssueView class. In this case IssueNumber property will be VolumeNumber.

Comment: As "view" prefix i mean that it is only short, only display-and-search purpose information, and in any case you may have extended class with many other properties (Price for example)

Comment: I think I see now. In my case -- Issue with a Volume-typed property that I can set with XmlNode.ParentNode property.

It doesn't seem OO, but maybe XML->Objects is sneaky that way.

Comment: Yes, often XML data have different purposes than OO